# How to "session.getAttribute" when using @SessionAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know the "pet" object below is stored to session by using @SessionAttributes, but can I use session.getAttribute ? (such as ..  Pet pet = (Pet)session.getAttribute("pet")). I am not sure why I do not need a "Session Key". (We have to define the key when using session.setAttribute("id", id))

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/editPet.do")
    @SessionAttributes("pet")
    public class EditPetFormController {

        @Autowired
        private final Clinic clinic;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String setupForm(@RequestParam("petId") int petId, ModelMap model) {
            Pet pet = this.clinic.loadPet(petId);
            model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
            return "petForm";
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session attributes configured via `@SessionAttributes` are intended to be accessed as model attributes rather than by calling methods of `Session` directly, therefore their names are generated from the model attribute names automatically.

By default, session attribute name is the same as the model attribute name, so you can access it as `session.getAttribute("pet")` (see [`DefaultSessionAttributeStore`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/DefaultSessionAttributeStore.html)).

Comment: Fantastic! I am completely understand!